# Custom Pydantic JSON encoder ignored when composing BaseModels

Tags: python, json, pydantic

I have two Pydantic BaseModels (I am using version 1.10), one of them is used as the field of the other:

```
from datetime import datetime

from pydantic import BaseModel

class Asd(BaseModel):
    time: datetime

class Lol(BaseModel):
    asd: Asd
```

I want the time in the `Asd` class to be serialized in a custom way, ie I want only the year, month and day. I have successfully achieved this like so

```
class Asd(BaseModel):
    time: datetime
    
    class Config:
        json_encoders = {datetime: lambda dt: dt.strptime("%Y-%m-%d")}
```

```
>>> asd = Asd(time=datetime.strptime("2020-01-01 00:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
>>> asd
Asd(time=datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 0, 0))
>>> asd.json()
'{"time": "2020-01-01"}'
```

When I serialize `Lol` I would expect the same behaviour to be enforced, however the custom encoding disappears

```
>>> Lol(asd=asd).json()
'{"asd": {"time": "2020-01-01T00:00:00"}}'
```

How can I make `Lol` implement the json serializer of `Asd`?

Comment: This is a [known issue](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/2277) in Pydantic v1 and is essentially solved in v2 with the [`_serializer` decorators](https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.2/usage/serialization/#custom-serializers).

Answer (score 0):

Moving the custom json encoder configuration to the `Lol` class solves the problem.

```
class Asd(BaseModel):
    time: datetime
    
class Lol(BaseModel):
    asd: Asd
    
    class Config:
        json_encoders = {
            datetime: lambda t: t.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        }
```

```
>>> asd = Asd(time=datetime.strptime("2020-01-01 00:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
>>> Lol(asd=asd).json()
'{"asd": {"time": "2020-01-01"}}'
```

However, this may not be enough for some applications, where it may be desirable for a BaseModel to implement the custom serializers of the other BaseModels that it has as fields.

As pointed out in the comments:

> This is a [known issue](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/2277) in Pydantic v1 and is essentially solved in v2 with the [_serializer decorators](https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.2/usage/serialization/#custom-serializers).